# Why validation score and actual result in pretrained models are contradictory?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, resnet, pre-trained-model

I have using pretrained models Resnet50, Resnet50V2, VGG16 etc for a face recognition model. I have got above 80% validation accuracy. But when I try to see the predictions over the same validation set I am getting almost all wrong predictions.

This is the code that I'm using for seeing my predictions:

```
class_names = list(testing_set.class_indices.keys())

predictions = model.predict(testing_set)
predicted_labels = [class_names[np.argmax(pred)] for pred in predictions]

# Print actual file paths and predicted labels
print("Predictions:")
for filepath, label in zip(testing_set.filepaths, predicted_labels):
    print("{} - {}".format(filepath, label))
```

This is the output:

```
Predictions:
data/_preprocessed/Testing/1825003/12.jpg - 1825036M
data/_preprocessed/Testing/1825003/17.jpg - Meryl_Streep
data/_preprocessed/Testing/1825003/21.jpg - 1825029M
data/_preprocessed/Testing/1825003/26.jpg - Natalie_Portman
data/_preprocessed/Testing/1825003/29.jpg - Nicole_Kidman
data/_preprocessed/Testing/1825003/32.jpg - Meryl_Streep
data/_preprocessed/Testing/1825003/38.jpg - George_Clooney
data/_preprocessed/Testing/1825003/41.jpg - Nicole_Kidman
data/_preprocessed/Testing/1825003/44.jpg - 1825029M
data/_preprocessed/Testing/1825003/45.jpg - Natalie_Portman
data/_preprocessed/Testing/1825003/47.jpg - Natalie_Portman
data/_preprocessed/Testing/1825003/60.jpg - Natalie_Portman
data/_preprocessed/Testing/1825003/64.jpg - Natalie_Portman
data/_preprocessed/Testing/1825029M/photo_27.jpg - 1825030
data/_preprocessed/Testing/1825029M/photo_3.jpg - Meryl_Streep
data/_preprocessed/Testing/1825029M/photo_36.jpg - 1825029M
data/_preprocessed/Testing/1825029M/photo_37.jpg - 1825029M
data/_preprocessed/Testing/1825029M/photo_41.jpg - Nicole_Kidman
data/_preprocessed/Testing/1825029M/photo_43.jpg - 1825030
data/_preprocessed/Testing/1825029M/photo_44.jpg - 1825003
data/_preprocessed/Testing/1825029M/photo_47.jpg - 1825036M
```

and this is my pretrained model implementation:

```
from keras.layers import Input, Lambda, Dense, Flatten, Dropout
from keras.models import Model
from keras.applications.resnet import ResNet50
from tensorflow.keras.applications import ResNet152, ResNet152V2
from keras.applications import ResNet101V2, VGG16
from keras.applications.resnet_v2 import ResNet50V2
from keras.applications.resnet import preprocess_input
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

import numpy as np
from glob import glob

IMAGE_SIZE = [224, 224]
train_path = "data/_preprocessed/Training"
test_path = "data/_preprocessed/Testing"
resnet = Resnet50V2(input_shape=IMAGE_SIZE + [3], weights='imagenet',include_top = False)
for layer in resnet.layers:
  layer.trainable = False 
### Layers of the model 

x = Flatten()(resnet.output)
#x = Dropout(0.25)(x)
# Dense layer
prediction = Dense(15, activation = 'softmax')(x)

model = Model(inputs=resnet.input, outputs = prediction)

model.summary()
optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
model.compile(
    loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    optimizer=optimizer,
    metrics=['accuracy']
)
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    rotation_range=10,
    width_shift_range=0.1,
    height_shift_range=0.1,
    shear_range=0.1,
    zoom_range=0.1,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    vertical_flip=False,
    fill_mode='nearest')

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)
training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_path,
                                                 target_size = IMAGE_SIZE,
                                                 batch_size = 32,
                                                 class_mode = 'categorical')
testing_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(test_path,
                                                 target_size = IMAGE_SIZE,
                                                 batch_size = 32,
                                                 class_mode = 'categorical')
r = model.fit(
    training_set,
    validation_data = testing_set,
    epochs = 5, 
    steps_per_epoch = len(training_set), 
    validation_steps = len(testing_set)
)
```